# AWS PHP SDK is_readable() and file_exists()

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

After upgrading php and we are having config file issues. Does anybody else have this issue with the AWS PHP SDK on ec2, how did you resolve it? I am using roles for ec2 permissions, but it is still looking for the config file.

php 7.4

aws/aws-sdk-php: 3.209.15

Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/httpd/.aws/config) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/mysite.com/:/tmp/) in /var/www/mysite.com/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/DefaultsMode/ConfigurationProvider.php on line 152

Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/httpd/.aws/credentials) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/mysite.com/:/tmp/) in /var/www/mysite.com/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php on line 812

Code that is causing throwing the warning:

```
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\DynamoDb\SessionHandler;

$dynamoDb = new DynamoDbClient([
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2012-08-10'
]);

$sessionHandler = SessionHandler::fromClient($dynamoDb, [
    'table_name' => 'sessions',
    'session_lifetime' => 1440,
]);
```

Thank you for any insight or help.

Comment: Perhaps force it to use the `CredentialProvider::instanceProfile()` ([example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_provider.html)) instead of the default provider chain?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I created an empty /usr/share/httpd/.aws/ directory and set the open_base to allow access. I still do not understand how this is a requirement to remove the warning message. When the instance was created it was assigned the role to use.